# my character jumps too strong sometimes in unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

My character's jump is working fine in a straight line collider, then I noticed that when every-time my character jumps in a curve shape collider, my jump always turns too strong abnormaly. How can I fix this? I'll provide my initial code for jump movement below.

Here is the img :

[image]

Here is jump code:

```
float checkgroundradius = 0.50f;
public bool isgrounded2;
public Transform grouncheckslot;
public LayerMask LM;
public float JumpPower;

public float movespeed;
Rigidbody2d RB;

void Update () {

    if (isgrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        isgrounded = false;
        jumping = true;
        myanim.SetBool("groundedanim", isgrounded);
        myrb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpower));

    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    isgrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(checkslot.position, groundradius, LM);
    myanim.SetBool("groundedanim", isgrounded);
    myanim.SetFloat("verticalspeed", myrb.velocity.y);

    float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    RB.velocity = new Vector 2 (move * movespeed, RB.velocity.y);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When jumping up the slope, your `Physics2D.OverlapCircle` intersects with the slope, thus making `isgrounded=true`, making you apply more force if the UpArrow is pressed.

Once solution could be to check that your character is not already moving upwards before jumping

```
if (isgrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && myrb.velocity.y <= 0.0f)
```

this way you wont jump again if you are already heading upwards.

Maybe you could play around with a smaller `groundradius` and/or try moving the `checkslot.position` in a way that it doesnt intersect with the slope in the same manner.

Comment: Ok thank you sir,  so whats happening now is he can still jump on the slope but in a stationary manner not a propelling jump type and that is what I want. a big help.

Answer (score 2):

For jumping people use `Rigidbody2D.AddForce` with `Forcemode.Impulse`.

Also, change

```
if (isgrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
```

to

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && myrb.velocity.y == 0)
```

So you don't need to `bool isgrounded`

I hope it helps you :)